# executing order, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken vs didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: ios, cocoa, delegates

my class with protocal(UIApplicationDelegate)

```
@interface BangAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@end
```

and BangAppDelegate have methods

```
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken
```

and

```
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
```

`didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is a function for registering APNS.
I want to know the executing order. 
Which function is called first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did finish launching with options first, then didRegister/FailedToRegister gets called depending whether the registration with the APNs server succeeds or not.